# How to pull email addresses from Sage50

Tags: crm, accounting, sage-erp, sage50

Is there a way to pull all the email addresses ever entered from Sage50?

I have tried report designer and csv export, to no avail.

I can export a huge number of phone numbers, but would ideally like email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "ever entered" unless you do some fiddling with the archive data.

If you want the current email data you can just do an obdc query.

```
 SELECT ACCOUNT_REF, NAME, EMAIL, EMAIL_2, EMAIL_3, DIRECT_DEBITS_EMAIL FROM SALES_LEDGER;
```

https://docs.zynk.com/workflow/developers/sage-50-uk-schema/sage-50-uk-sales_ledger-columns.html